# Initialize final variable in Flutter widget - best practice

Tags: flutter, dart

Sometimes we need to initialize final variables in Flutter UI widgets with non const value (so we can't add it as default value). Which is the best way to do that?

There are three ways I see:

**1. Initialize in build method.**
It allows us to declare `const` constructor, but as the variable will be recreated on every build - it doesn't seem to be a good way.

```dart
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomeWidget({super.key, this.date});

  final DateTime? date;

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    final dateToShow = date ?? DateTime.now();

    return...
```

**2. Initialize variable through constructor.**
It looks good, but we lose `const` modifier for constructor.

```dart
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SomeWidget({super.key, final DateTime? date}) : _date = date ?? DateTime.now();

  final DateTime _date;
  
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return...
```

**3. Initialize variable in a state of `StatefulWidget`.**
It also looks OK. We have `const` modifier again and as there is no `setState()`, it won't affect performance heavily. But there are more boilerplate and the additional instance will be created - instance of the `State`.

```dart
class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SomeWidget({super.key, this.date});

  final DateTime? date;

  @override
  State<SomeWidget> createState() => _SomeWidgetState();
}

class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  late final _date;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _date = widget.date ?? DateTime.now();
  }
```

The last two ways both look good. Which one is more performant and can be considered as the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually 2 is recommended and conventional way. Why do you need a **const** widget in your scenario? The `DateTime.now()` is always different. What's the point?

The meaning of `final` keyword (and also `readonly` in C#) is that the identifier should hold a runtime constant value that never changes during its lifetime.

In other places like functions, `final` has no special meaning as functions run scoped. You usually do not need a final variable in your functions. The role of a function is usually to mutate something whereas final is used to mark something immutable.

In the above case it makes sense the widget not to be const because it totally makes sense to rebuild the widget whenever the date changes.

If date never changes then you can just have a hard coded date string in your widget tree.

3 is not recommended not just because the `setState` but a state full widget runs bunch of lifecycle methods that produces added overheads.