# Initialising a final function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

**What is the way to initialise this function if required?** It is supposed to be passed to the constructor.

`final void Function(String) onChanged;`

Here is the partial code: Compiler is complaining of uninitialised final variables.

```
class CustomDynamicTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final String? initialValue;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDynamicTextBoxState();
}
```

**Now when I do pass them to the constructor, the compiler stops complaining. Why is that so?**

```
class CustomDynamicTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
 
  final String? initialValue;
  final void Function(String) onChanged;

  const CustomDynamicTextBox({this.initialValue, required this.onChanged});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDynamicTextBoxState();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77113167/initialize-final-variable-in-flutter-widget-best-practice
or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864913/how-do-i-initialize-a-final-class-property-in-a-constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in three different ways,

1. Using `typedef` to declare your `void Function(String) onChanged`
   then use it as a variable assigning a vale to it.
2. Using Anonymous methods.
3. Using directly the method you want to pass as a
   parameter.

In this example you can see the three methods used commented by type.
The first one used is by `typedef` usage:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef MyOnChanged = void Function(String value);

class CustomDynamicTextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? initialValue;

  // final void Function(String value) onChanged;
  //  Toogle comments form this one and that above
  final MyOnChanged onChanged;

  const CustomDynamicTextBox({required this.initialValue, required this.onChanged, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDynamicTextBoxState createState() => _CustomDynamicTextBoxState();
}

class _CustomDynamicTextBoxState extends State<CustomDynamicTextBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () =>
          widget.onChanged.call(" 'This value will be printed as the new value' and this: '${widget.initialValue}' is the initial value"),
      child: const Text("Click me"),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('CustomDynamicTextBox Example'),
      ),
      body: const StartWidget(),
    ),
  ));
}

// Typedef usage
class StartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartWidget({super.key});

  MyOnChanged get myOnChanged => (String value) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Value changed: $value");
        }
      };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomDynamicTextBox(initialValue: "Ciao da Italia", onChanged: myOnChanged);
  }
}

// Anonymous usage
class StartWidget1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartWidget1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomDynamicTextBox(
      initialValue: "Ciao da Italia",
      onChanged: (String value) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("Value changed: $value");
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

// Method usage
class StartWidget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartWidget2({super.key});

  void printNewValue(String value) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("Value changed: $value");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomDynamicTextBox(
      initialValue: "Ciao da Italia",
      onChanged: printNewValue,
    );
  }
}
```